# How to set NPOI excel chart title style (Overlay = false)?

Tags: styles, overlay, title, npoi

```
XSSFChart chart;
chart.SetTitle();
```

*I know how to set the title, but can't find a way to set the title not to overlay the chart*

Answer (score 2):

```
chart.GetCTChartSpace().chart.title.overlay = new CT_Boolean() { val = 0 };
```